# How to report a malicious script?

Tags: malware, javascript

I recently received an email with some malicious script written in JavaScript which affects DLLs. I just want to know if there is a kind of security board or something along those lines where I can submit my malicious script. This can be useful to avoid others being affected by this malicious script.

Comment: Try virustotal.com, submit there a file via web upload.

Comment: Thank you, you can't tell if this website use the file for analysis purpose but I can see that some antiviruses already classified it as malicious.

Answer (score 0):

[This excellent guide](https://decentsecurity.com/#/malware-web-and-phishing-investigation/) by [@SwiftOnSecurity](https://twitter.com/SwiftOnSecurity) lists multiple notable services where you can report the malicious script to.

> 1. [VirusTotal.com](https://virustotal.com) (Shares reports publicly, shares files with Premium subscribers)
> 2. [Hybrid-Analysis.com](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/) (Shares reports and files publicly, uses Payload Security's VxStream sandbox)
> 3. [Malwr.com](https://malwr.com) (Shares reports and files publicly)
> 4. [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/portal/submission/submit.aspx) (Select 'Home User')
> 5. [Webroot](http://snup.webrootcloudav.com/SkyStoreFileUploader/upload.aspx) (Detections and threat intelligence go to multiple other products)
> 6. [Kaspersky](https://scan.kaspersky.com)
> 7. [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/reports/malware) (Especially for files that came through email, used in many spam filters)
> 8. [Emsisoft](https://www.emsisoft.com/en/support/submit/)

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/how-do-i-report-new-malware has a much larger list with email addresses