# I know where I downloaded a virus, should I report it somewhere

Tags: virus

I was installing pytool forge and accidentally downloaded virus (clicked wrong link). Should I report this link somewhere? Are there plans to create global virus police task force? I am sorry, it is broad and probably off topic, but what is the proper space to ask these type of questions?

Comment: upload it to virus total

Comment: @VipulNair sure it will simply check and tell me, if it is virus or not. But would not law enforcement be interested in who is behind distribution of this virus, who is trying to benefit from it.

Comment: Law enforcement won’t care at all unless you file a theft complaint. Depending on the amount of your losses, they probably still won’t investigate. Most computer crimes like this are way, way out of their jurisdiction.

Comment: potential duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/where-to-report-malicious-urls-phishing-and-malicious-web-sites or https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/how-do-i-report-new-malware

Answer (score 2):

Most antivirus companies have submission forms for malware where you can upload a sample: e.g. https://www.gdatasoftware.com/securitylabs

But in the end it really doesn't make a big difference, there is millions of different types of malware out there and AV companies will get most of their samples through automated collection through their products.

Unless you found the next Stuxnet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet) reporting your malware sample isn't worth your time.

Answer (score 1):

Report it to your anti-virus company. (You are running AV, aren’t you?) They should be able to gather some info from your computer about the virus, and develop a signature for it.