# Honeypot URL and reporting site

Tags: exploit, webserver

Is there some sort of tool list that can work with Apache/NGinx/etc that has a list of "honeypot" URLs such as `/HNAP1/` that when it gets detected in the logs of the web server then it will automatically report to some other site like those in [Where to report malicious URLs, phishing, and malicious web sites?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/where-to-report-malicious-urls-phishing-and-malicious-web-sites)

It does not have to be part of the web server itself ie a module, it could also be a log analysis tool.

Comment: When it gets detected by what? What is the purpose of reporting it?

Comment: Still not sure what you are asking. What are you hoping will happen if you report it?

Comment: Dunno. Make the internet a better place. I mean why have honeypots to begin with.

Comment: hold on - you want to eliminate honeypots?

Comment: how would reporting the request for access of a non-existent honeypot URL be useful?